# Layout ClipDrawable not working

Tags: java, android, layout

My ClipDrawable throws exception when I try to set level of cliping of the ImageView through code. Logcat points beside others on line *img.setLevel(...)* too.  What's wrong in my code?

clip.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

ImageView in layout

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:background="@drawable/clip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
```

Code (after setContentView(layout))

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1); 
        ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) img.getDrawable();
        img.setLevel(drawable.getLevel() + 1000);
```

EDIT: log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at game.gam.Game.prepniNaLevelLayout(Game.java:356)
            at game.gam.Game.onImageButtonClick(Game.java:163)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Always show the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I've edited main post.

Comment: Have you done step through debugging?  It looks like your drawable is null.

Comment: Hm yes, it looks like "drawable" is null, but no idea why. Code is ok but drawable null.

Comment: Javadoc for getDrawable says "Return the view's drawable, or null if no drawable has been assigned"

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. I've checked image name, it's image.png, clip.xml is in drawable folder... I did all steps from android docs ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip ), no success..

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but found it looking for a solution to a different problem. OP's issue is they're trying to set the ImageView's background instead of source. From my experience image.getDrawable() is looking for the android:src tag, which is why the OP was getting a null. Should be:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:src="@drawable/clip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
```